# Error while using distinct method rails4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, distinct

I am using rails4 with mysql database. I want to fetch the unique name and I am using distinct method.
Product Template

```
<%= collection_select(:metal, @product.id, @product.metal_specs.all, :id, :unique_name) %>
```

MetalSpec model

```
def unique_name
  self.select(:name).distinct
end
```

But its giving me an error- private method `select' called for MetalSpec.

Please help me to solve this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 has_many :metal_specs , -> { distinct }, through: :metals
```

Solved this way. :)

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to call select on the model MetalSpec whereas you want to call select on a collection.

Its hard to tell without knowing your schema but maybe you need something like

```
self.metal_specs.select(:name).distinct
```

in your product model

Comment: unique_name is defined in MetalSpec model. Error is on calling select method.

Comment: @dips, what model has the attribute 'name' and what collection of these models are you trying to select from, all the models or just those  belonging to another object.

Comment: I Want to select the name from only those MetalSpecs which is associated with the product. Name is the attribute of MetalSpec model.

Comment: Please tell me -if I use self.metal_specs.select(:name).distinct in product model then how can I call this method on collection_select?

Answer (score 0):

Your code is calling select on an instance.

Also - if you are after just a list of names, I'd suggest you use pluck. As this is returning a list of names, I think the method should be plural

```
def unique_names
  metal_specs.pluck(:name).uniq
end
```